# Inherited javascript property not set during constructor

Tags: javascript, inheritance, constructor, properties

I have two Javascript classes, one extends the other.

The base class has a property, which is overridden by the other class.

When constructing the subclass, the property appears to be set as per the superclass.

I tried searching for this, but did not find any useful results - possibly I don't know the correct search terms.

Example:

```js
class A {
  id = "A";
  constructor() {
    this.show();
  }

  show() {
    console.log(this.id);
  }
}
class B extends A {
  id = "B";
}

o = new B();
o.show();
```

Since I'm constructing a "B", I expected it to print "B" and "B", but actually it prints "A" and "B".

How do I get "B" in the superclass constructor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to the order that all the properties are added and initialized. It starts with the base class, working out to the final subclass.

When you create a `B`, it first creates an `A`, which does `this.id = 'A'` and then calls the `A` constructor. This calls `this.show()`, which logs `A`.

Then it finishes contructing the `B` part of the object, which does `this.id = "B"`. Now when you call `o`.show()`, you get the` B` output.

You generally have to be careful about how you operate on the object during construction, because it's still in an intermediate state.

Comment: is there any way to say "once construction is complete, call this" ? (from the superclass)

Comment: No, because the parent class constructor doesn't have any control over the child class. The parent class is out of the picture by then.

Comment: There's nothing that runs automatically after all constructors have finished.

Comment: Constructors should just be used for constructing. If you want to debug, use a debugger and you can step through everything.